# How to configure sub domain name IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, dns, subdomain, hosting

I work in a organization that has a certificate *.mycompany.com

I developed a ASP.NET CORE API and [hosting my endpoints as windows servic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)e. How can i set the host name for my API like *myapi.mycompany.com*? I can able to browse with *servername:port.mycompany.com*

There are already some sites configured on the same server which i deployed my application on port **7788**

I gave a try and searching all articles in google and stack overflow but none of them understandable to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

**servername:port.mycompany.com** is not a standard host name format.  If you means that you can access the site via servername.mycompany.com:port. Then you should already have a local active domain and DNS forward lookup zone **mycompany.com**.

So please create an alias(CNAME) **api** for your host(A) servername.mycompany.com. Then its FQDN should be api.mycompany.com.  Once you register DNS.

You should run ipconfig /flushdns and access the website via myapi.mycompany.com. If you don't want to expose port number. Please set your port number `ASPNETCORE_URLS` to 80.

Comment: You are right, I meant to say servername.mycompany.com:port

Comment: @Dinesh Have you set subdomain for your application?

Comment: I can't set the CNAME on my organization and informed to respective team